# Android Animation black border

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-theme

I am animating a activity transition with `overridePendingTransition()` using this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" 
          android:toYDelta="0" 
           android:duration="@string/animationDuration"/>
  </set>
```

For the enter animation and

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<translate android:fromYDelta="0" 
               android:toYDelta="100%p
            android:duration="@string/animationDuration"/>
</set>
```

for the exit animation.
The thing is that i get a black border between the two activities when animating them. The animation is a push out animation, where it looks like the new activity pushes the old one out, the border I am talking about is the space between the old and the new activity.

I am using the theme `NoTitleBar` found in `android:style`. The border looks like its as wide as a titlebar, can it have something to to with that? Anyhow I need to remove this border, how would i do that?

Comment: Any chance you can attach a screen shot?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "between" them? It's not clear what exactly is happening.

Comment: try with Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen in manifest. i think this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm!